# IIS Wordpress Not Load Css Js Content On Windows Server 2012

Tags: css, wordpress, iis

I Have virtual Server With Public Ip 45.156.**.**
My Os Is Windows Server 2012 and Install IIS 8.5.9600
I Install Php on IIs And I Can Install wordpress Succesfull
My Website Host On Locolhost port 80
[image]

in local show website correct and load all css style js file and images
but when call website from internet with ip 45.156.**.** do not load css js files
[image]
[image]

[image]

Folder Permission
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously that your client is requesting statif file from http://localhost directly.
I think you need to set an outbound rule to rewrite src attribute to the correct domain.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

Check your WordPress settings to make sure it's configured to work with the IP address.

Go to the WordPress dashboard, navigate to Settings > General, and ensure that both the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" are set to the IP address (e.g., http://ip-address:port).